# How can I go back to the previous view controller?

Tags: objective-c, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

When user click "OK" button from UIAlertController popup, it will go back to the previous view controller.I got stuck how to that.Below this is my code.

```
if (jsonData == nil){
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"This Git repository is empty" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:ok];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
if (jsonData == nil){
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"This Git repository is empty" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
            // Ok action example
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }];
        [alertController addAction:ok];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Awesome..its work!..thnx sir..almost 2hour i'm looking for this answer.

Comment: Glad to help you.